# Python and Pi Rc Car

Tags: python, bluetooth, keylistener

Ok so i'm working on controlling an rc car with the keyboard directional keys, using Python and a Raspberry pi, I was just wondering if i need to use PyGame, or something similar, or if Python has a built in key listener, i was hoping to progress onto using an xbox controller, but would like to get it working from the key board first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Pygame to read joysticks, but you'd eventually need GPIO to flow current to the motors. As such, I'd probably use GPIO for button input as well. See the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZSiqj0NZgU) for more.